# File upload only pictures

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I am using the fileupload control in asp.net. I want the browser to only show pictures. I am currently using validation to ensure they only select images but how can I make the browser only search for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, like Mark said it is not possible. But you could implement a filtering in javascript but i suspect you already know it's possible. if not, [check this post](http://aspalliance.com/1614_Adding_Filter_Action_to_FileUpload_Control_of_ASPNET_20.all)

Answer (score 1):

You can't (unless you implement a Silverlight or Flash solution).

Answer (score 0):

you can verify with javascript if the ending is allowed.

also, what most of the websites does, is that they stop the transfer after the max. data size (1 meg, 4 meg etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Using pure HTML + JavaScript, I believe you can't, you'll need to check on server-side. You could maybe do what you want if you use a Flash uploader (like Flickr does), but that may not be applicable for you.